# JavaScript - concatenate string with variable to reference another variable

Tags: javascript

this may be a basic question, but I'm at a loss how to do it. I'm extracting a number (**2**) from the name of a clicked button. Then I want to concatenate that number with a string to reference a variable (`lineOpt1_**2**`) and set another variable (`varLine`) with that newly concatenated variable. This is done in adobe captivate (`cpAPInterface`).

```
var but_name = this.document.activeElement.getAttribute("id");

var n = but_name.split('_').pop(); 

window.cpAPIInterface.setVariableValue('varLine', "lineOpt1_"+n);
```

Could someone help me with the 3rd line? the others work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but it seems like what you are doing is setting the variable `varLine` to the string `"lineOpt1_2"`.

I *think* what you are trying to do is set the variable `varLine` to whatever the variable `lineOpt1_2` contains?  In which case, you can do:

```
var value = window.cpAPIInterface.getVariableValue("lineOpt1_"+n);
window.cpAPIInterface.setVariableValue('varLine', value);
```